# iOS programming - how to zoom in and zoom out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do you increase or decrease the size of a UIImageView in Obj-C? For example, I want a picture of duck to grow larger and larger. I can't find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about pint-to-zoom, see Trevor's answer.  But if you just want to programmatically increase the display size of the view, just modify the `frame` property of the `UIImageView`.  If you increase the size of the view, the image will scale to fit.

Answer (score 2):

If your talking about pinch-to-zoom, you must use a `UIScrollView`.  Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922).

If you're looking to make the image animate from smaller to larger, use a `UIView` animation block on the `UIImageView`